# Guess the word game in Java

Tags: java, string

i have a problem writing guess the word game java code .
i'll show you my current code and till you the problem .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Q
{
    public static void main(String argss[])
    {
        String strs[] = { "kareem", "java", "izz", "tamtam", "anas" };
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int index = ((int) (Math.random() * 5));
        int points = 50;
        String c;
        boolean result = false;
        boolean finalResult = false;
        boolean tempResult = false;

        String word = strs[index];
        System.out.println(
                "\t *** Enter a character and guess the world*** \n\t ***You will loose if your points become 0 *** \n ");
        System.out.println(stars(word));
        System.out.println("Your points: " + points);
        System.out.print("Enter and guess a character! ");

        String temp = stars(word);
        String oldTemp = temp;

        c = input.next();
        while (points > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            {
                result = (word.charAt(i) + "").equals(c);
                if (result == true)
                {
                    temp = toChar(i, temp, c);
                }

            }

            finalResult = temp.equals(word);
            tempResult = temp.equals(oldTemp);
            System.out.println(temp);
            if (finalResult == true)
            {
                System.out.println("\n \n YOU HAVE GUESSED THE WORLD,YOU WON ! ");
                break;
            }
            if (tempResult == true)
            {
                points = points - 5;
                System.out.println("False and now your points are " + points);
            }

            else if (tempResult == false)
            {
                System.out.println("True and now your points are " + points);

            }
            if (points <= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\n\n*********************\n* Sorry , you loose *\n*********************  ");
                break;
            }
            System.out.print("Guess another time,enter a character: ");
            c = input.next();
        }

    }

    public static String stars(String word)
    {
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
            temp = temp + "*";
        return temp;
    }

    public static String toChar(int index, String temp, String c)
    {
        char[] tempChar = temp.toCharArray();
        char s = c.charAt(0);
        tempChar[index] = s;
        temp = String.valueOf(tempChar);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

now as you can see in line number 39 , i have a little problem here because when its false it'll be no longer right .
do you know another way to compare if the entry is right or not ?

Comment: Um, which line is 39?

Comment: @bradimus tempResult=temp.equals(oldTemp);

Comment: Unfortunately, my telepathy is not working right now so I can't tell which line is line 39. Could you share it with us Izzeddin?

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj 'tempResult=temp.equals(oldTemp);'

Comment: @IzzeddinEda'is It's not clear what your problem is. Can you please elaborate. What is your current result? What is your expected result? The better you explain your problem, the better results you will get from this community.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you are changing `oldTemp` inside the while loop. Try setting it to equal to `temp` after all of the if statements.

```
if (points <= 0)
{
    System.out.println("\n\n*********************\n* Sorry , you loose *\n*********************  ");
    break;
}
oldTemp = temp; // add this here
System.out.print("Guess another time,enter a character: ");
c = input.next();
```